# returning a value in sync and await in dart

Tags: dart

I am trying to understand the usage of async and await in Dart. Somehow I am having issues returning values in certain methods.

Consider the code below

```
Future<int> getMrn() async {
  var mrnRef = await firebaseClient.child('mrn');

  DataSnapshot ss;
  StreamSubscription<Event> onValueSubscription = await mrnRef.onValue
      .listen((event) {
    ss = event.snapshot;

    return ss.val();
  });

  //return Future<int> ss.val();
}
```

`mrn` is of type `int` which should be returned by `getMrn` method. However each time the returned `ss.val()` returns `null`. It seems that `ss = event.snapshot` is not seen in the last returned value

What is the correct way of doing this.
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the code above, you're declaring anonymous function `(event){..}` as a callback, and your `return` statement relates to it, while your intention was to `return` from `getMrn()`.

What are you actually need, is to **complete** a `Future` you're returning from `getMrn()` inside your callback.

Like this:

```
Future<int> getMrn() async {
  var mrnRef = await firebaseClient.child('mrn');

  Completer<int> c = new Completer<int>();
  StreamSubscription<Event> onValueSubscription = await mrnRef.onValue
      .listen((event) {
    DataSnapshot ss = event.snapshot;
    c.complete(ss.val());
  });

  return c.future;
}
```

but that code wouldn't work good if there second event appear in `mrnRef.onValue` stream. So, assuming `mrnRef.onValue` is a `Stream`, and you need only first event, it would be better to rewrite it this way:

```
Future<int> getMrn() async {
  var mrnRef = await firebaseClient.child('mrn');

  Event event = await mrnRef.onValue.first;
  DataSnapshot ss = event.snapshot;
  // note, you're implicitly returning a Future<int> here,
  // because our function is asyncronous
  return ss.val();
}
```