# return List of Strings from Future / Stream

Tags: dart, flutter

My Problem is very similar to the one mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50738381/how-to-return-a-string-from-a-function-which-is-listening-some-stream-in-dart) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31072085/returning-a-value-in-sync-and-await-in-dart), but for some reason these are not working for me.

Basically, I want to do some simple I/O operations (on a mobile), returning of list of strings (folder path) that contain a certain file format (let's assume for the sake of argument that I want to find all mp3 files).

This is the code I have

```
Future<List<String>> getFolders() async {
  List<String> _dirs = new List();
  await SimplePermissions.requestPermission(Permission.ReadExternalStorage);
  _dirs = await findAllFolders();
  return _dirs;
}

Future<List<String>> findAllFolders() async {
  Directory _root = Directory("/sdcard");
  bool _notInList = true;
  List<String> _dirs = new List();

  _root.list(recursive: true, followLinks: false)
  .listen((FileSystemEntity entity) {
    if(entity.toString().contains("mp3")) {
      if(_dirs.length==0) {
        _dirs.add(entity.parent.path.toString());
      } else {
        _notInList = true;
        for (var i = 0; i < _dirs.length; ++i) {
          if(_dirs[i] == entity.parent.path.toString()) {
            _notInList = false;
          }
        }
        if(_notInList) {
          _dirs.add(entity.parent.path.toString());
        }
      }
    }
  });
  return _dirs;
}
```

where I want to use _dirs outside of getFolders().

I know that findAllFolders() returns _dirs immediately, before my listen() event has finished (and so its length is always 0, although the actual method works fine, i.e. if I put print statements where I have _dirs.add() I can see that the correct directories are added, _dirs contains what I want but I have no idea how to return the finished _dirs list). I tried to do something in a similar way to the above mentioned post, where a Completer is used (to which I am getting an error message "Bad State: Future already completed"). The respective code would be

```
Future<List<String>> findAllFolders() async {
  Directory _root = Directory("/sdcard");
  bool _notInList = true;
  List<String> _dirs = new List();

  Completer<List<String>> _completer = new Completer<List<String>>();
  _root.list(recursive: true, followLinks: false)
  .listen((FileSystemEntity entity) {
    if(entity.toString().contains("mp3")) {
      if(_dirs.length==0) {
        _dirs.add(entity.parent.path.toString());
      } else {
        _notInList = true;
        for (var i = 0; i < _dirs.length; ++i) {
          if(_dirs[i] == entity.parent.path.toString()) {
            _notInList = false;
          }
        }
        if(_notInList) {
          _dirs.add(entity.parent.path.toString());
        }
      }
    }
    _completer.complete(_dirs);
  });
  return _completer.future;
}
```

The getFolders() function remains the same in this case. Could anyone point out where my logic is going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting a listener, then immediately returning before any results are received - that's why your return is always empty. The body of `findAllFolders()` needs to wait for a response before returning. Try the below to replace `_root.list().listen()`:

```
  List<FileSystemEntity> files = await _root.list(recursive: true, followLinks: false).toList();

  for (FileSystemEntity entity in files) {
    // Do your filename logic and populate _dirs
```